# Is there a way to vertically align Arabic font with English font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Here is an example:

```css
h1{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <h1>English Font</h1><h1>الخطوط العربية</h1>
```

As you can see the base lign isn't aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the `line-height`

```css
h1{
  display:inline-block;
}
.arabic {
  line-height: 25px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
    <h1>English Font</h1><h1 class="arabic">الخطوط العربية</h1>
```